# How to control a boolean in redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, switch-statement

It seems like I can't dispatch boolean values. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

This is my state:

```
const initState = {
  allSongs: songData(),
  currentSong: { ...songData()[0] },
  isPlaying: false,
};
```

**How can I control `isPlaying` with the dispatch function?** When I dispatch it like this, it doesn't work:

```
      dispatch(playAndPause(true));
```

With this being my action creator:

```
export const playAndPause = (isPlayingBool) => (dispatch) => {
  return {
    type: PLAY_AND_PAUSE,
    payload: {
      isPlaying: isPlayingBool,
    },
  };
};
```

Reducer:

```
case PLAY_AND_PAUSE:
      return {
        ...state,
        isPlaying: action.payload.isPlaying,
      };
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where you change the state?

Comment: @SinanYaman Yes, I edited the post to include that too.

Answer (score 2):

What you have there `playAndPause` is no normal action creator, but a thunk action creator.
That innermost function would be called and allowed you to do asynchronous actions before actually dispatching. If you **wanted** to go that route, the correct way would be

```js
export const playAndPause = (isPlayingBool) => (dispatch) => {
  // do some stuff here
  dispatch({
    type: PLAY_AND_PAUSE,
    payload: {
      isPlaying: isPlayingBool,
    },
  });
};
```

But really, you probably want a normal action creator:

```js
export const playAndPause = (isPlayingBool) => ({
  type: PLAY_AND_PAUSE,
  payload: {
    isPlaying: isPlayingBool,
  },
});
```

Also, please note that you are writing a pretty old style of redux here. If you are learning redux right now, please stop whatever tutorial you are following and follow the [the official tutorials](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index) instead.
In the end, you will write maybe 1/4 of the code you will be writing with the current style you are using.

Modern redux does not require you to write any action creators or action type constants for example. It also has no switch...case reducers or immutable logic in reducers.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the new style. I Iooked it up and have converted my redux file to this style. But implementing thunk is a bit confusing. Can you show me how you would write a thunk action creator in the new style? Should I be following this tutorial to get to that? https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk

Comment: You can still use normal thunks, which is perfectly valid. If your thunks dispatch some kind of `started` action at their beginning and a `success` or `error` action at the end, `createAsyncThunk` will do that for you.